# jQuery multiplying and adding all values together of fields with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have a few `<input>` elements that look like this:

```
<input id="hosts" name="250" class="hostselector" type="number" min="0" max="999" value="0" />
```

I would like to multiply the value (that the user enters) with the value I'm storing in name.

Now there's several elements of this on the page, all with the `class="hostselector"`. I'd like to get the sum of all the values, so in a sense:

```
(value * name) + (value * name) + .... every single element with that class.
```

How would I do that using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var total = 0;
$(".hostselector").each(function() {
    total+= parseInt(this.value, 10) * parseInt($(this).attr("name"), 10);
});
```

This loops through all elements with class `.hostselector`, multiples the current value by the value of the `name` attribute (which is a string, hence the use of `parseInt`), and maintains a running total of all elements.

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mYbn/3/) showing it working (just click the button to see the final result).

Comment: I think you could also replace '$(this).attr("name")' with "this.name", or are there browser compatibility problems with that?

Comment: @asawilliams - good point, you could absolutely do that. There shouldn't be any browser compatibility problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

It should go something like this:

```
var total = 0;
$('.hostselector').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10) * parseInt($(this).attr('name'), 10);
})
```

The "total" var holds the number you are looking for.

The parseInt part is more or less optional, javascript will still return you the right result without it, but because .val() and .attr() return you strings it is the proper thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    var sum = 0;   
    $.each('.hostselector', function(i ,item){
    sum +=  $(item).val();
    // or sum += $(item).attr("Your_Attribute_here");
    });
    alert(sum);
```