# Multiplying text put value with the sum of check box values and display it on a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to multiply the entered text input value with the sum of check box values clicked. So far when you click the check boxes the sumof their avues is displayed instantly on the span emlement with id="Totalcost"....i need some help figuring out how i could multiply the sum of check box selected with the value entered in the text input field.

If it can be easily done using JQuery i will really appreciate

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var total = 0;
     inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
    function test(item){
 var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');
      if(item.checked){
           total+= parseInt(item.value);
        }else{
           total-= parseInt(item.value);
        }
        //alert(total);
        document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total ;
    }



    </script>
 
  </head>
  <body>
<input type="text"  id="chatinput" onchange="myFunction()"><br>
<p id="printchatbox"></p>
    <div id="container">
    <p id="printc"></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="channcost" value="10" onClick="test(this);"  />10<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chanlcost" value="20" onClick="test(this);" />20 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chancost" value="40" onClick="test(this);" />40 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chanlcost" value="60" onClick="test(this);" />60 <br />
    </div>
    Total Amount : <span id="Totalcost"> </span><BR><BR><BR>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/m65gdjzm/

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613294/jquery-multiplying-and-adding-all-values-together-of-fields-with-a-certain-class

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, but it seams not to work .... but your code has helped me alot....i have just done some little edits to it and it worked. Check this link http://evansonmwakio.com/test3.html  thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

You have many incongruences in your code.....

Replace it with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var total = 0;
function test(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName("input");
    var box_value = parseInt(document.getElementById('chatinput').value);
    var new_total = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
        var item = checkboxes[i];
        if(item.checked){
            new_total += parseInt(item.value);
        }
    }
    if(box_value>0){ total = (new_total>0?new_total:1) * box_value; }
    else{ total = new_total; }
    document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total ;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text"  id="chatinput" onchange="test()"><br>
<p id="printchatbox"></p>
<div id="container">
    <p id="printc"></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="channcost" value="10" onClick="test();"  />10<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chanlcost" value="20" onClick="test();" />20 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chanlcost" value="40" onClick="test();" />40 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="chanlcost" value="60" onClick="test();" />60 <br />
</div>
Total Amount : <span id="Totalcost"> </span><BR><BR><BR>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your script to make these changes

```
    var total = 0;
    function test(item){
    var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');
      if(item.checked){
           total+= parseInt(item.value);
        }else{
           total-= parseInt(item.value);
        }
        inputValue = $("#chatinput").val();
        textValue = (isNaN(inputValue)) ? 1 : parseInt(inputValue);
        if(textValue == "NaN"){
            textValue = 1;
        }
        totalAfterMul = total*textValue;
        console.log(totalAfterMul);
        document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = totalAfterMul ;
    }
```

It will do what is desired. 
It takes the input value and then multiply it with the sum of the check boxes. If the input value is not a number then it will consider it as 1

```
inputValue = $("#chatinput").val();
textValue = (isNaN(inputValue)) ? 1 : parseInt(inputValue);
if(textValue == "NaN"){
    textValue = 1;
}
totalAfterMul = total*textValue;
```